# Listing all equivalence relations

Tags: equivalence-relations

I am unsure how to find the all the equivalence relations.  I know that a relation is an equivalence relation if it is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.  However I'm still uncertain how to find them all.

Comment: If you want to list all the equivalence relations, then you should be writing a list of sets of pairs of elements of $A$. Right now, I only see one set of pairs of elements of $A$.

Comment: I thought I wrote out all the pairs.  What pairs am I missing

Comment: "*List* **of sets** *of pairs*"

Comment: so would it be what I wrote up there plus {(1,1)} , {(2,2)}, {(3,3)}

Comment: Those three additional relations you wrote are not equivalence relations on $A$.

Comment: It may help to note that there is a bijection between the set of equivalence relations over a set and the set of partitions over a set.  The trivial equivalence relation where everything is related to everything, that is, $1\simeq 2\simeq 3$, corresponds to the partition $\{\{1,2,3\}\}$.  The other trivial equivalence relation $\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)\}$, that is elements are only related to themselves, corresponds to the partition $\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\}\}$.  There are still three more partitions... the one where $1=2\neq 3$, the one where $1=3\neq 2$, and the one where $1\neq 2=3$

Answer (score 2):

Let us recall the definition of an equivalence relation $R$ on a set $S$. It means the following hold:

- Reflexivity: for all $s \in S$, $(s,s) \in R$ (emphasis on **for all**)
- Symmetry: Whenever $(a,b) \in R$, so is $(b,a)$
- Transitivity: Whenever $(a,b),(b,c) \in R$, so is $(a,c)$

Bear in mind that the first condition requires that $(a,a),(b,b),(c,c) \in R$ for all equivalence relations $R$, so the "minimal size" relation $R$ is

$$R = \{ (a,a),(b,b),(c,c) \}$$

unlike what you're suggesting in the comments elsewhere.

---

It might be easiest to visualize this exercise through a table:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
  & a & b & c \\
\hline
a &   &   &   \\
\hline
b &   &   &   \\
\hline
c &   &   &   \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Put a mark in a given square. Then it will mean that $(x,y)$ is in the relation $R$, where $x$ is the element from the left and $y$ the element from above.

To be an equivalence relation, we need to be reflexive, transitive, and symmetric. Reflexive would require a mark on all elements of the diagonal as so:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
  & a & b & c \\
\hline
a & X &   &   \\
\hline
b &   & X &   \\
\hline
c &   &   & X \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

What else? Well, this already gives one equivalence relation, trivially. Suppose we add more pairs to $R$ that are non-diagonal entries. Then we would have to add the pair that is flipped across the diagonal, sort of like taking the transpose of a matrix. That means if you mark $(a,b)$ you have to mark $(b,a)$ too, and vice versa.

Just be sure to mark off further pairs that transitivity also has to imply!

---

Transitivity also has a condition related to this table method, but we instead have to use a condition that is slightly more formal and perhaps harder to visualize. Relations can be envisioned as matrices, where the rows and columns represent the elements, $0$'s are in the unrelated entries, and $1$ in the related entries. That is, for example,

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
  & a & b & c \\
\hline
a & X &   &   \\
\hline
b &   & X &   \\
\hline
c &   &   & X \\
\hline
\end{array} \implies R = \left[ \begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix} \right]$$

In this case, the conditions are

- Reflexivity: All entries in the diagonal of $R$ are nonzero.
- Symmetry: $R = R^T$.
- Transitivity: Find $R^2$. If the nonzero entries in $R^2$ and those in $R$ are in the same position, we have transitivity.

---

Finally, as pointed out, just be sure you enumerate all of the equivalence relations. You only found one, but as you have already seen above, there's at least one you forgot.

Comment: This is correct, but I think not a good approach for beginners. Using the fact that equivalence relations are just partitions is better than using the square of the matrix to check transitivity.

Comment: I think this might be it now but i'm still not sure if this is all of them                                                                             { (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3) } and {(1,1), (2, 2), (3, 3)} and { (1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,2), (3,3)}  and { (1,1), (1,3), (2,2), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3) } and { (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,3), (3,1), (3,3) }

Answer (score 1):

That is *one* of the equivalence relations on the set: the relation in which everything is equivalent to everything else. There's another in which the only pairs are $(x,x)$: each element is related only to itself.

To find all the others, think about or look up the connection between equivalence relations and partitions. Here's one reference:

https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/Monroe_Community_College/MTH_220_Discrete_Math/6%3A_Relations/6.3%3A_Equivalence_Relations_and_Partitions

Comment: so would it be what I wrote up there plus {(1,1)} , {(2,2)}, {(3,3)}

Comment: What you wrote plus $\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)\}$ plus some others. Read the reference I suggested.